# Magento: Stored Procedures in SQL Upgrade Scripts

Tags: php, stored-procedures, magento

I've been trying to put a stored procedure creation step into my SQL upgrade script in Magento.
like

```
$this->startSetup();
$sql = <<< __SQLPRC
CREATE PROCEDURE my_proc(
    IN length int
    ,IN column_used_for varchar(50)
    ,OUT return_id bigint
)
BEGIN
    DECLARE count_unused INT;
    SET count_unused = 0;
    select 
            id into return_id
        from 
            my_table
        where 
            used_status=0
            limit 1;

    if length(return_id) = length 
    then
        update my_table
            set 
                used_status=1
            where 
                id = return_id;
    else
        set return_id = 0;
    end if;
END;
__SQLPRC;

try {
$this->run($sql);
}
catch(Exception $e)
{ echo "<pre>" . $e->getTraceAsString(); }

$this->endSetup();
```

What I've concluded from my debugging is that Magento just grabs the SQL till first semi-colon "`;`"
Can somebody help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have put the Stored Procedure code as:-

```
$this->startSetup();
$sql = <<< __SQLPRC
...
```

This needs to be as:-

```
$this->startSetup();
$sql = <<<__SQLPRC
...
```

This should work now, as there shouldn't be any space after the "`<<<`" according to the **[Heredoc Syntax](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)** of PHP String Delimiting.

Hope it helps.

---

**Updated Answer:-**

Can you try using this code:-

```
$write = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
$write->exec($sql);
```

instead of:-

```
$this->run($sql);
```

I have seen some issues earlier regarding this on Magento.

Comment: Nopes, still the same issue :(
It still doesnt consider anything after the first semi-colon.

Comment: Just wanted to note, you can specify a .sql script instead of .php for your modules SQL installation. take a look at  app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php `_modifyResourceDb`

Comment: Even with using an SQL file, it just considers the query till the first SEMI COLON.

Comment: Debugging further down the line, i discovered that problem lies with 
_splitMultiQuery() function  in lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php being called in following sequence

run() calls multi_query() calls _splitMultiQuery()

this function splits query on basis of semi-colon and executes each piece individually.
Any suggestions further ?

Comment: @Knowledge-Craving: thanks a tonne. using exec() in lieu of run() works.

Comment: @Sonic - Most Welcome & Cheers... Actually the method "`run()`" executes each query individually, based on the semicolon mark. However, the method "`exec()`" executes the whole SQL in a single time. So, your solution can be achieved more fruitfully using this "`exec()`" method.